# Reading data from a link

Tags: python

I have a wiki link @http://wiki.company.com/company/w/index.php?title=test&action=edit whose data looks like below in HTML...
is there a way I can get the block that has test Combo?any built-in python modules,appreciate inputs

```
INPUT:-

=== find ===

data1

==== <font color="#008000">test Combo</font> ====

{| border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
|-
test
|}

==== next bloock ===

data3

OUTPUT:-
{| border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
|-
test
|}
```

Comment: You'll want to look into regular expressions.

Comment: dont gun me down..i just need inputs an algorithm..i will update based on inputs receivied

Comment: If you want to access the original wiki markup for a page and are using MediaWiki, try changing the `action=edit` part to `action=raw`.  That might be a better starting point than the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a way to download the file in question. The standard python module for doing so is urllib2.

Then you need a way to process the HTML file. Two good python modules suited for the task are [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) and [lxml](http://lxml.de/).